# Accessing variable outside class using inheritance

Tags: python, class, variables, inheritance

I am trying to inherit a variable from base class but the interpreter throws an error.

Here is my code:

```
class LibAccess(object):
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url = url

    def url_lib(self):
        self.urllib_data = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url).read()
        return self.urllib_data

class Spidering(LibAccess):
    def category1(self):
        print (self.urllib_data)


scrap = Spidering("http://jabong.com")
scrap.category1()
```

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "variable_concat.py", line 16, in <module>
    scrap.category1()
  File "variable_concat.py", line 12, in category1
    print (self.urllib_data)
AttributeError: 'Spidering' object has no attribute 'urllib_data'
```

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: `urllib_data` is added only in the `url_lib` function. You might want to call the function before printing `urllib_data`

Comment: the problem lies in the fact that in LibAccess' __init__() and url_lib(), you are assigning a value to an attribute of an object (i.e. and instance of the class), not to the class. `self.var` creates `var` in the namespace of self (i.e. the object, the instance of the class LibAccess). You have never created such object.
What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define `self.urllib_data` prior to accessing it. The simples way would be to create it during initialization, e.g.

```
class LibAccess(object):
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url = url
        self.urllib_data = None
```

That way you can make sure it exists everytime you try to access it. From your code I take it that you do not want to obtain the actual data during initialization. Alternatively, you could call `self.url_lib()` from `__init__(..)` to read the data for the first time. Updating it later on would be done in the same way as before.

Comment: but i want to get this "urllib_data" data instead of None

Comment: @Mounarajan: in that case call self.url_lib() during the initialization as suggested in my answer.